# Node deploy failing because container did not respond to warmup request

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express, deployment

I'm deploying a node app to azure and the deploy is failing because the container is not responding to the warmup request. The app starts locally, and is listening on the same port as the warmup requests. Here are the deploy logs:

```
2022-10-29T06:01:45.287Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container 
customcalligraphy_0_9c31f200 for site customcalligraphy
2022-10-29T06:03:45  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2022-10-29T06:04:45  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2022-10-29T06:05:45  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035657849Z    _____
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035686150Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035691350Z  /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035695650Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035699650Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035703750Z         \/      \/                  \/
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035707650Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035711351Z
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035714951Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035718651Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035722451Z NodeJS Version : v18.2.0
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035726151Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2022-10-29T06:01:45.035729951Z
2022-10-29T06:01:45.152855802Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2022-10-29T06:01:45.215494733Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2022-10-29T06:01:45.235215447Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2022-10-29T06:01:45.242910847Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2022-10-29T06:01:45.242928347Z Build Operation ID: feba110f-d139-44e2-b66c-0e10cff5c53d
2022-10-29T06:01:45.476505931Z Environment Variables for Application Insight's IPA Codeless Configuration exists..
2022-10-29T06:01:45.522707434Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2022-10-29T06:01:45.595152421Z Running #!/bin/sh
2022-10-29T06:01:45.595192122Z
2022-10-29T06:01:45.595198422Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2022-10-29T06:01:45.595204922Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2022-10-29T06:01:45.595210723Z
2022-10-29T06:01:45.595215423Z export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2022-10-29T06:01:45.595220223Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2022-10-29T06:01:45.595224923Z      export PORT=8080
2022-10-29T06:01:45.595229723Z fi
2022-10-29T06:01:45.595234423Z
2022-10-29T06:01:45.595239023Z npm start
2022-10-29T06:01:47.149225225Z npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2022-10-29T06:01:47.149401829Z npm info using npm@6.14.15
2022-10-29T06:01:47.150028044Z npm info using node@v18.2.0
2022-10-29T06:01:47.346984068Z npm info lifecycle custom-calligraphy-ecommerce@1.0.0~prestart: custom-calligraphy-ecommerce@1.0.0
2022-10-29T06:01:47.348375300Z npm info lifecycle custom-calligraphy-ecommerce@1.0.0~start: custom-calligraphy-ecommerce@1.0.0
2022-10-29T06:01:47.352639898Z
2022-10-29T06:01:47.352662299Z > custom-calligraphy-ecommerce@1.0.0 start /home/site/wwwroot
2022-10-29T06:01:47.352681799Z > node index.js
2022-10-29T06:01:47.352686199Z
2022-10-29T06:01:48.466127815Z STARTING CUSTOM CALLIGRAPHY SERVER
2022-10-29T06:01:49.692607132Z CCvbeta1.1 Listening on port 8080!
2022-10-29T06:01:50.344268374Z serving app
2022-10-29T06:02:21.332686762Z serving app
2022-10-29T06:02:52.341610061Z serving app
2022-10-29T06:03:23.343535160Z serving app
2022-10-29T06:03:54.350896814Z serving app
2022-10-29T06:04:25.361345562Z serving app
2022-10-29T06:04:56.364076228Z serving app
2022-10-29T06:05:27.370947666Z serving app
2022-10-29T06:05:57.383Z ERROR - Container customcalligraphy_0_9c31f200 for site customcalligraphy did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 252.0962469 sec
2022-10-29T06:05:57.401Z ERROR - Container customcalligraphy_0_9c31f200 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-10-29T06:05:57.408Z INFO  - Stopping site customcalligraphy because it failed during startup.
```

My app is actually running, but the deploy is failing. Here is my serverside code:

```
console.log("STARTING CUSTOM CALLIGRAPHY SERVER");

const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "frontend", "build")), () =>
  console.log("serving app")
);

app.use(express.json({ limit: "5gb" }));
const port = process.env.port || 8080;

const version = "beta1.1";
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`CCv${version} Listening on port ${port}!`));
```

How can I disable the warmup request or respond to the pings? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- I would suggest use of express-generator to create the app. Just run

```
npx express-generator myapp
```

- Then you can add your code in the `app.js` file.
  my app file looks like this

```
console.log("STARTING CUSTOM CALLIGRAPHY SERVER");
const  express = require("express");
const  path = require("path");
const  app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "frontend", "build")), () =>
    console.log("serving app")
);
app.use(express.json({ limit:  "5gb" }));

const  port = process.env.port || 8080;
module.exports = app;
```

- Here instead of listening to the ports in the `app.js` file we export the `app` entity and all the listening of port will be done in the `www` file.
- This `www` also call the `app.js`  file and will run app.
- Now you can just deploy the app by you preferred way of choice. Here I have used vscode.
- This way you will not get the `could not find javascript build manifest file` errors

logs after deployment of app :

[image]

- Also use port 80 as it is already exposed in the app service.